# Enum value doesn't seem to be persisting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game and I am attempting to set the difficulty via buttons. So I have three buttons, easy, medium, hard and of course when you click which ever one it sets the difficulty.

The problem is, even if my difficulty seems to be set, when the game starts it is incorrect.
Please see my code below.

```
public enum GameDifficulty
{
    Test,
    Easy,
    Medium,
    Hard
}
internal GameDifficulty Mode;//= GameDifficulty.Easy;

public void setToTest()
{

    Mode = GameDifficulty.Test;
}

public void setToEasy()
{
    Mode = GameDifficulty.Test;
}

public void setToMedium()
{
    Mode = GameDifficulty.Medium;
}

public void setToHard()
{
    Mode = GameDifficulty.Hard;
    Debug.Log("sET TO Hard");
}


//[Information("Selece Game Mode", MoreMountains.Tools.InformationAttribute.InformationType.Info, false)]
/// Set Variables based on selected mode
    // public motionDirections motionState = motionDirections.Vertical;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    var storm = stormHerald.GetComponent<WindEffect>();
    Debug.Log(Mode);
    switch (Mode)
    {
        case GameDifficulty.Test:
```

Now, when I click the "hard button, I get the debug that it's been set to hard, however, on start the debug shows that it's actually being set to test. I am of the opinion that this is because of how my "Mode" variable is defined but I am unable to solve it.

Would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: You could add a None option to your enum.

Comment: @mchts What would that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly see the problem in the question, but a misunderstanding of what the code should be doing.

`Mode` is not initialized and gets the default value for the enum, that is the first possible value in this case. Please see here for more enum documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum

Pressing those buttons will NOT make the state of Mode persist. You have to keep in mind that if you want the state to persist you have to save it. One way to do that is through Player Settings: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html

If you're pressing those buttons in pre-game mode, then that state will not be transfered or preserved to the final product or the game mode, as the classes are reloaded every time we recompile (this has to be understood as a simplification of what Unity is doing under the hood).

Answer (score 1):

The problems are here:

> `internal GameDifficulty Mode;//= GameDifficulty.Easy;`

and here:

> `Debug.Log(Mode);`

I don't see any initialization of `Debug.Mode` variable. In your comment, you say you set it to easy, but how do you know that? I don't see any assignment that does that.

Modifying the code to

`internal GameDifficulty Mode=Test;//= GameDifficulty.Easy;`

(or Easy or whatever) should fix this.

Comment: That will work yes, but not what I was going for. I was trying to set that value from `public void setToEasy()` because my button calls it. Im trying to set up a UI where the player can change the game difficulty.